# Windows Builder plugin of Eclipse not working in Linux

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop a new RCP application in Linux environment, earlier I have developed RCP applications on Windows Environment. I knew that [windowsBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro) serves best for GUI development of RCP. But, here it doesn't look like to be working.

Here are the additional details:
1. Eclipse version: Kepler Release
2. My Windows Builder Plugin downloaded site : [google Eclipse](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7)
3. My Linux environment details :

**Linux MINT**

- Release 13 (maya) 32-bit
- Kernel Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
- GNOME 3.4.2

The screen shot of the design page for a sample view in my rcp application is hereunder:

[image]

The problem, in the above image is there are 2 components in the view i.e.., a label and a button but are not shown in the view to the right side.

As a workaround, I tried installing from different update [sites](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) but it did not work for me.

#### UPDATE:

Error Log from error view:
Message : Unhandled event loop exception
stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.gef.part.AbstractComponentEditPart$1.paintClientArea(AbstractComponentEditPart.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paintFigure(Figure.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paintChildren(Figure.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paintChildren(Figure.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paintChildren(Figure.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.FigureCanvas.handlePaint(FigureCanvas.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.FigureCanvas.access$2(FigureCanvas.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.FigureCanvas$3.handleEvent(FigureCanvas.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1416)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_expose_event(Control.java:3165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_expose_event(Composite.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.gtk_expose_event(Canvas.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4569)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8707)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2287)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3361)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Comment: did you look into eclipse logs?

Comment: @AlexStybaev : Yes, updated question with log info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins might be conflicting.And why not directly use an [Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/keplerr) version.The WindowBuilder plugin is included and you don't need to download it.

> Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers :
>
> A complete set of tools for developers who want to create Eclipse plug-ins and Rich Clients (RCP), or develop with the Remote Application Platform (RAP), plus Mylyn, XML editors, Code Recommenders, Git, CVS, and Maven integration.